# Best Way to declare a LUT in OpenCL (Intel FPGA)

Tags: opencl, fpga, lookup-tables, intel-fpga

I need to declare three LUT's in an OpenCL kernel, so:

What is the optimal way to declare a LUT in Intel OpenCL FPGA?

I have saw examples about this, but in the examples they used a `switch/case` structure. I think the best way is declare an array for each LUT, as in the following example (example taken from: [how to declare a constant array of float2 vectors?](https://community.khronos.org/t/how-to-declare-a-constant-array-of-float2-vectors/2783)):

```
__constant float2 foo[2] = {1.0f, 0.0f};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `switch/case` if you cannot address the elements in the LUT array directly, i.e. if your lookup positions do not follow `0,1,2,...,N`. It's more elegant to implement the LUT as an array and do direct addressing with `lut[position];`.
If the LUT is small enough and you only need it in one place, you can have it in `private` memory space within the kernel. If the LUT is larger (than several hundred entries), you need to divert to `constant` memory space; element accessing remains identical.